# WP8 BUG: Code signing identity mismatch when installing from a company hub

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, installation

I discovered a Windows Phone bug.

Here is the case:

- A device is enrolled for 2 company accounts: "Foo" and "Bar".
- I have a XAP file signed by "Bar"
- If from Internet Explorer, I provide the XAP file a simple link from a web page, I get a correct dialog stating "Do you want to install the application from "Bar"?"
- If I use a company hub signed by "Foo", then, when I provide the XAP file URL from the company hub to invoke the InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync method to install the app, I get a message stating "Do you want to install the application from "Foo"?"...

...which is wrong, as "Foo" has not signed the XAP file I am about to install.

Is this bug already known by Microsoft? Is there a way to workaround it?

Answer (score 1):

The Company Hub is an application like others, which must itself be signed by the company certificate to be deployed on mobile.

```
   InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync(String, Uri)
```

This installs the remote .xap file on the mobile.

```
   InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher
```

will allow us to recover all the packages installed on the phone from the SAME Publisher that the current application (i.e. of the Hub app). So beware, we no longer speak of the certificate to identify the packages, but simply the Publisher ID stored in WMAppManifest.xml file. Make sure that your packages have the correct Guid. This identifier is available in your account information on Windows Phone Dev Center.

This method returns an IEnumerable . The Package class has the benefit of offering two useful methods:

- GetThumbnailToken to retrieve the application Thumbnail.
- Launch to start the application directly from the Company Hub.

  InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher()

This method returns all the app packages (Package objects) installed on the phone with the same Publisher ID as the Company Hub app that calls this method. 
So if you have an application with different publisher id than that of the Company hub, there is no reason for this company hub to show such an app. So may be through the hub app, the publisher id is changed to that of the hub app.. or all apps installed through the hub have the same publisher id as the hubs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I totally agree with you that the use case to reproduce the bug I saw is not logical. However, it could happen. Let's consider that you have a catalog of apps available for installation, every XAP file sharing the same Publisher ID value in WMAppManifest.xml, but some of the XAP files are signed by CompanyA certificate, whereas others are signed by CompanyB certificates (mot logical, but possible). Then, if your Company Hub is signed by CompanyA, installing an app signed by CompanyB will show you a dialog stating "Do you want to install app from CompanyA?"... This what I think is wrong.

Comment: What is loose with the XAP signing process is that you are can signed a XAP file even if the publisherID value in WMAppManifest.xml is not the one that is linked to the code-signing certificate.

Comment: I believe that the XAP signing process should check that the publisher ID is the one expected, and fail if it is not.